# Why doesn't MSBuild match Path properties?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, finalbuilder

I have a reference to a custom assembly.  Looking at the Assembly Properties I see

`Path = C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\Assembly.Namespace\v4.0_3.0.0.0__c199d42a01e99449\Assembly.Namespace.dll`

When I look at the .cs project MSBuild I see

```
<Reference Include="Assembly.Namespace, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c199d42a01f89449, processorArchitecture=x86">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\..\Project DLLs\Folder Name\Assembly.Namespace.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

The paths do not match.  It also appears that the .NET runtime version doesn't match.  When I build my project's in Visual Studio which uses [Csc.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd.aspx) it works.  When I use FinalBuilder which uses [MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx) the build breaks.

Comment: Because you didn't specifically reference the assembly from the GAC but the one in your project?

Comment: @JeffMercado - The DLL does not exist at the hint path.  I deleted that folder.  This project should not build (AND in fact when you use FinalBuilder it does not build).  But it still builds in visual studio.  I don't get it.

Comment: Well it's just that, a hint.  When you reference an assembly, it will try to look in the locations you specify.  If it fails, it would look in other accessible locations (such as the current directory or GAC). At least, that's how I understand it all works.

Comment: @JeffMercado - That doesn't explain why the finalbuilder build fails using MSBuild.  VS uses CSC.exe. I have a feeling the issue lies in the difference between the two.